# How to format a phonenumber

Tags: format, twig

I am looking to format a phone number with twig.
Basically, I wanted to separate every 2 digits with this function and it works perfectly when I have a 10-digit phone number like 0600000000:

```
   {% set splitPhone = store.phones['phone_store']|split('', 2) %}
   {% set phone = splitPhone|join(' ') %}
```

I get what I want:

> 06 00 00 00 00

The problem is that my data can also arrive in the form: +336000000

so in that case I get

> +3 36 00 00 00

I would like something like : + 336 00 00 00

In this case, I would like to find a general technique to ensure that if my number is 10 digits, it does as I currently do but in case there is the "+" in front, it separates it from the digits.

Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just extend twig with a custom filter which solves this for you, e.g.

```
$twig->addFilter(new \Twig\TwigFilter('format_phone', function($phone) {
    $prefix = null;
    if (strpos($phone, '+') === 0) $prefix = substr($phone, 0, 4).' ';
 
    $temp = str_split(substr($phone, $prefix ? 4 : 0), 2);
    return $prefix.implode(' ', $temp);
});
```

[demo](https://ideone.com/CyjiSJ)

```
{{ '0600000000'|format_phone }}
{{ '+336000000'|format_phone }}
```